# Client-Server Android, Trying to reference Socket by Creating Array for Each user

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets

I have a program which looks for Client Connections and then stores the socket in an array of object of class that I created,

The Class that I created:

```
public class UserManagement{
String userName;
Socket clientSocket;
public UserManagement(Socket soc,String usrN){
    clientSocket = soc;
    userName = usrN;
}
public Socket getSocket(){
    return clientSocket;
}
```

}

The class which accepts client connections:

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            Socket soc;
            BufferedReader read;
            ser = new ServerSocket(4444);
            while(lookforusers){
                soc = ser.accept();
                read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
                String str = read.readLine();
                usrName[userCount] = str;
                try{
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.obj = str;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }catch(Exception e){Log.d("st",e.toString());}
                usrLst[userCount] = new UserManagement(soc,str);
                userCount++;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){Log.d("serverThread", e.toString());//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }
```

Now when the first time as the connection is established the communication is alright, but when I try to communicate in an another thread with the help of Array of Object that I created it doesn't work.

```
class SendThread implements Runnable{
    Datas data;
    SendThread(Datas data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<Launch.userCount;i++){
            try{
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(Launch.usrLst[i].getSocket().getOutputStream());
                Object obj = data;
                out.writeObject(obj);
            }catch(Exception e){Log.e("",e.toString());}
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing it currently on a single android phone by installing to different application.

Comment: You need to read the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial. You need to start a new thread per accepted connection to handle all the I/O with that client. There is generally no need for a collection of client sockets at all: each of these threads just manages its own, and exits when the connection drops.